# Is Subscription part of the domain following ddd principles?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to understand DDD principles. And for practice, i want to have subscription. And i am wondering in a saas application for the sake of example, the user can only access the app if he is a subscriber and has an active subscription.

Is subscription part of the domain? If yes, when dealing with an third party like Stripe Payment, should our aggregate Subscription be aware of some data from Stripe like payment_method_id for the reccurent billing?

For me, Subscription is part of the domain model since there are some business rules (authorization, access_control).

I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at "Context Maps". They show the relationship between Bounded Contexts.

To answer your question: yes a Subscription is part of your domain and therefore part of some Bounded Context within your control. Stripe is a Bounded Context not within your control.

So how you model stripe in your solution depends on the relationship and strategy thereof (see context maps). Are you `Conformist`? Are you in need of an `Anti Corruption Layer`? Are you in a `Customer/Supplier` relationship?

A conformist approach could well be to model all stripe properties AS-IS in your domain model. It is up to your understanding of the relationship